# Is it possible to do Rcpp::wrap without copying for a very large std::vector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, htslib

I have an Rcpp function that reads large BAM file (1-20GB, using `htslib`) and creates several very long `std::vector`s (up to 80M elements). The number of elements is not known before reading, so I cannot use `Rcpp::IntegerVector` and `Rcpp::CharacterVector`. As far as I understand, when I `Rcpp::wrap` them for further usage, the copy is created. Is there a way to speed up the transfer of data from C++ to R in this situation? Is there a data structure that can be created within Rcpp function, be as quick to `push_back` elements as `std::vector` is, and passed by reference to R?

Just in case, here's how I create them currently:

```
std::vector<std::string> seq, xm;
std::vector<int> rname, strand, start;
```

And here's how I wrap and return them:

```
Rcpp::IntegerVector w_rname = Rcpp::wrap(rname);
w_rname.attr("class") = "factor";
w_rname.attr("levels") = chromosomes;  // chromosomes contain names of the reference sequences from BAM

Rcpp::IntegerVector w_strand = Rcpp::wrap(strand);
w_strand.attr("class") = "factor";
w_strand.attr("levels") = strands;  // std::vector<std::string> strands = {"+", "-"};
      
Rcpp::DataFrame res = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(
  Rcpp::Named("rname") = w_rname,
  Rcpp::Named("strand") = w_strand,
  Rcpp::Named("start") = start,
  Rcpp::Named("seq") = seq,
  Rcpp::Named("XM") = xm
);
      
return(res);
```

**Edit 1 (2021.10.19):**

Thanks to everyone for comments, I need more time to check if `stringfish` can be used, but I ran a slightly modified test from cpp11 package vignettes to compare it with `std::vector`. Here's the code and results (showing that `std::vector<int>` is still faster despite it must be `Rcpp::wrap`ped upon return):

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> stdint_grow_(SEXP n_sxp) {
  R_xlen_t n = REAL(n_sxp)[0];
  std::vector<int> x;
  R_xlen_t i = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    x.push_back(i++);
  }

  return x;
}')

library(cpp11test)
grid <- expand.grid(len = 10 ^ (0:7), pkg = c("cpp11", "stdint"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b_grow <- bench::press(.grid = grid,
                       {
                         fun = match.fun(sprintf("%sgrow_", ifelse(pkg == "cpp11", "", paste0(pkg, "_"))))
                         bench::mark(
                           fun(len)
                         )
                       }
)[c("len", "pkg", "min", "mem_alloc", "n_itr", "n_gc")]

print(b_grow, n=Inf)

# A tibble: 12 × 6
        len pkg         min mem_alloc n_itr  n_gc
      <dbl> <chr>  <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int> <dbl>
 1      100 cpp11     1.9µs    1.89KB  9999     1
 2     1000 cpp11     6.1µs   16.03KB  9999     1
 3    10000 cpp11   58.11µs  256.22KB  7267    12
 4   100000 cpp11  488.15µs       2MB   815    11
 5  1000000 cpp11    4.34ms      16MB    88    14
 6 10000000 cpp11   97.39ms     256MB     4     5
 7      100 stdint    1.6µs    2.93KB 10000     0
 8     1000 stdint   3.36µs    6.45KB  9998     2
 9    10000 stdint  19.87µs    41.6KB  9998     2
10   100000 stdint 181.88µs  393.16KB  2571     4
11  1000000 stdint   1.91ms    3.82MB   213     3
12 10000000 stdint  36.09ms   38.15MB     9     1
```

**Edit 2:**

`std::vector<std::string>` is marginally slower than `cpp11::writable::strings` in these test conditions, but more memory-efficient:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<std::string> stdstr_grow_(SEXP n_sxp) {
  R_xlen_t n = REAL(n_sxp)[0];
  std::vector<std::string> x;
  R_xlen_t i = 0;
  while (i++ < n) {
    std::string s (i, 33);
    x.push_back(s);
  }

  return x;
}')

cpp11::cpp_source(code='
#include "cpp11/strings.hpp"

[[cpp11::register]] cpp11::writable::strings cpp11str_grow_(R_xlen_t n) {
  cpp11::writable::strings x;
  R_xlen_t i = 0;
  while (i++ < n) {
    std::string s (i, 33);
    x.push_back(s);
  }

  return x;
}                
')

library(cpp11test)
grid <- expand.grid(len = 10 ^ (0:5), pkg = c("cpp11str", "stdstr"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b_grow <- bench::press(.grid = grid,
                       {
                         fun = match.fun(sprintf("%sgrow_", ifelse(pkg == "cpp11", "", paste0(pkg, "_"))))
                         bench::mark(
                           fun(len)
                         )
                       }
)[c("len", "pkg", "min", "mem_alloc", "n_itr", "n_gc")]

print(b_grow, n=Inf)

# A tibble: 12 × 6
      len pkg           min mem_alloc n_itr  n_gc
    <dbl> <chr>    <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int> <dbl>
 1      1 cpp11str   1.22µs        0B 10000     0
 2     10 cpp11str   3.02µs        0B  9999     1
 3    100 cpp11str     22µs    1.89KB  9997     3
 4   1000 cpp11str 765.28µs  541.62KB   602     2
 5  10000 cpp11str  66.69ms   47.91MB     8     0
 6 100000 cpp11str    6.83s    4.62GB     1     0
 7      1 stdstr     1.38µs    2.49KB 10000     0
 8     10 stdstr     1.86µs    2.49KB 10000     0
 9    100 stdstr    16.44µs    3.32KB 10000     0
10   1000 stdstr   898.23µs   10.35KB   511     0
11  10000 stdstr    73.55ms   80.66KB     7     0
12 100000 stdstr      7.54s  783.79KB     1     0
```

**Solution (2022.01.12):**

... for those who have similar question. In this particular case I didn't need to use `std::vector` data within R. So `XPtr` easily solved my problem, cutting BAM loading time nearly twice. The pointer is created:

```
std::vector<std::string>* seq = new std::vector<std::string>;
std::vector<std::string>* xm = new std::vector<std::string>;
```

and then stored as a `data.frame` attribute:

```
Rcpp::DataFrame res = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(                                
    Rcpp::Named("rname") = w_rname,
    Rcpp::Named("strand") = w_strand,
    Rcpp::Named("start") = start
);

Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::string>> seq_xptr(seq, true);
res.attr("seq_xptr") = seq_xptr;

Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::string>> xm_xptr(xm, true);
res.attr("xm_xptr") = xm_xptr;
```

and reused elsewhere as following:

```
Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::string>> seq((SEXP)df.attr("seq_xptr"));
Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<std::string>> xm((SEXP)df.attr("xm_xptr"));
```

Comment: If you use linux, I would recommend using mmap (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), and wrap around loaded values with a pointed structure.

Comment: It's an R/Bioconductor package and I wanted it to be available for all three platforms (Linux, Win and Mac). But even if Linux only - still can't figure out how that may help

Comment: In this situation it might be a good idea to wrap the vector into an [`XPtr`](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classRcpp_1_1XPtr.html) and pass it to R in this opaque package. Of course this precludes *using* it from within R. You’d need to write an ALTREP wrapper for it. Alternatively, why not use the existing packages from Bioconductor? This has all been implemented before.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks for a suggestion. I do not need to use this vector of strings within R, but do need to sort the resulting Rcpp::DataFrame (data.table) within R, so it'd complicate things to my understanding (although I can find a solution). Also, which Bioc packages you mean? If Rsamtools then that's what I'm trying to get away from, cause it's much slower than I want

Comment: @notch Fair enough, ‘RSamtools’ is … not good. However, even then you might want to use the data structures defined inside the ‘Biostrings’ package, and in particular the [C interface](https://github.com/Bioconductor/Biostrings/blob/master/inst/include/Biostrings_interface.h), and probably also ‘GenomicRanges’.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'm relatively new to Bioconductor, didn't know that Biostrings have C interface, will look at it. In a way, I am doing unnecessary work now by decoding 4-bit representation of a sequence string from BAM, but it makes the code of my package simpler. If I switch to BStrings I'd have to refactor quite a lot (which is possible of course). Anyhow, do you think there would be no significant overhead for "transferring" XStringSet from C to R?

Comment: Regarding comparisons you might want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/ldlasb) as well, Make sure you use Rcpp 1.0,7 too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, Aaall right, I see. But my conclusion is basically the same and I'm using Rcpp 1.0.7

Comment: Yes, the upshot still is that a) `std::vector<>` is _very_ hard to beat and b) the final copy is more-or-less unavoidable if you want to bring the data to R (and you don't write an ALTREP vector).  Also @KonradRudolph is quite right about `XPtr` but you could even be simpler and, say, keep a (one-off) "container" class off a static ptr in your file and just write a subset accessor.  Then you only need to copy the subsets vectors you request :)   As always, it all depends.

Answer (score 2):

We use `std::vector<>` because of its robust implementation coupled with *great* performance (as it is generally hard to see `std::vector<>` beat in any comparison).  But it uses its own allocator for memory held outside of R.

`Rcpp` returns objects to R that are indistinguishable from objects created by R as they use R's own data structure and that requires one final copy into memory used, owned and allocated by R.  There is simply no way around it with the current interface if you want to return all elements to R.

R now has ALTREP allowing for alternative / external representation so you could cook up something different, but it is in fact somewhat difficult as the API for ALTREP is still both somewhat incomplete and changing.  Some packages have been built using ALTREP but none comes to my mind right now for your particular use case.

*Edit:* For your string vectors you could (and should) try the [stringfish](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stringfish) package by Travers. It uses ALTREP for strings, which may be your bigger performance hurdle. For the `int` vector I do not have an alternative but maybe the final `memcpy` there is also not that painful (as opposed to strings which are handled differently internally making them more expensive).

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout @dirk-eddelbuettel ;). Maybe time to revisit this issue? https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1096.

Comment: Or wait for you to write `numberfish`  :grin: